# Why will focus() not work on div element?

Tags: javascript

```
  var targetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('hello-world-div')[0];
  var focusElement = document.activeElement;
  console.log("currently focused on: ");
  console.log(focusElement); //this shows the body element  

  targetElement.focus();
  focusElement = document.activeElement;
  console.log("forced focus on: ");
  console.log(focusElement); // this still shows the body element
```

Why does the focus element not change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add tabIndex attribute to the "hello-world-div" element so that focus() and blur() could work!

Comment: Consider removing the `reactjs` tag and modifying the title if this question turned out to be unrelated to React.